# Lazy evaluation of any Closure in PHP

Tags: php, closures, lazy-evaluation

I'm looking for a context-independent deferred Closure evaluation. In pseudocode:

```
// imagine there's a special type of "deferred" variables
$var = (deferred) function () {
    // do something very expensive to calculate
    return 42;
};

// do something else - we do not need to know $var value here,
// or may not need to know it at all

var_dump($var * 2);
// after some million years it prints: int(84)

// now this is the hardest part...
var_dump($var); // notice no brackets here
// prints immediately as we already know it: int(42)
```

Last step is crucial: such way we can pass a variable (or a class member) around without anyone knowing what it actually is up to the point they're using it.

Clearly I can't do exactly that right in the language, because even with strings `__toString()` magic method would not replace the original value. Not even it's going to work with anything else than strings:

```
// this will fail
function __toString()
{
    return new Something();
}
```

Sure, I can wrap around a Closure with another object, but this means everyone up the stack would have to know how to deal with it. And this is what I'm looking to avoid.

Is this even remotely possible? Maybe there's somewhere a hacky PECL to do this or something similar.

Comment: Hi @sanmai did you per change found any way to do that ? I want to do the same thing and cannot find a way without having to "call" the function / object / closure to get the value.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want are memos.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

This is one of those undocumented features in PHP. Basically you declare a static variable *within* the closure and use it as a cache.

```
$var = function(){
    static $foo; // this is a memo, it sticks only to the closure
    if (isset($foo)) return $foo;
    $foo = expensive calculation
    return $foo;
};

var_dump($var()); // millions of years
var_dump($var()); // instant
```

This will lazy evaluate and cache the calculation.

If you mean "defer" as in run them in the background, you can't because PHP is not multi-threaded. You would have to set up multi-process workers or use pthreads.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: Nice try. You can't access such a variable directly, without brackets. It isn't transparent to the user (requires special treatment), hence not much better than a wrapper object with a method to resolve. (Defer here isn't related to other defers.)

Comment: Unless you are passing around an object that uses __get(), what you're trying to do can't be done without parenthesis. I think requiring no parenthesis is unrealistic, dishonest, and can't be done without __get(). My answer is correct. Sorry.

Comment: That is also not the subject of the question. Closures are functions. They must be invoked.

Comment: I want a closure to be invoked *behind the scene*, invisible to a user, and it's result stored in the variable it is assigned to. Guess what: there's no point for me to ask someone to do this *with brackets*, because I, too, can invent a bunch of methods to do that with them.

Comment: You can now that I showed you. I don't think you have the slightest idea of what you are doing.

Comment: Old thread but you can sort of do what @sanmai wants via  __toString(). You wouldn't use a memo for that, it'd be stored as an instance variable, and you'd only be able to stash strings. It's a hack for sure.

Comment: I wanted something like Scala's `lazy val` but since 2014 I managed to [create a package of my own to solve this problem](https://github.com/sanmai/later).

Comment: @sanmai you made a whole package to accomplish what a memo already does. try this: $deep=function(){static $memo; return $memo ??= DeepThought()}; $deep();
--
DeepThought() is only evaluated once. then it's stored/returned from the memo. the next call will just return 42 immediately. this is what i was trying to explain to you 10 years ago lol. hope you are well.

Comment: Yup, memorization is what my package does but for any closure and without any shortcomings of static variables.

Comment: @sanmai what shortcomings

Comment: unit testing is impossible, tightly coupled code, excessive global state, memory leaks